# calculating a parameters in equation

Tags: r

```
SMDIt=p*SMDIt-1+q*SMDt
SMDIt=SMDt/50
```

I want to do the above equation to my dataset (SMD). I first need to divide the first column of my dataset with 50 (eqn 2)and call it SMDI, then go for  first equation where i add SMDIt-1  with the original SMD.I have two values of p and q (p_dry and p_wet, q_dry and q_wet). I want to use p_dry and q_dry if my cell value is positive otherwise p_wet and q_wet in equation one. I wrote a following code but it gives me error. NA/NAN argument. Please help.

```
3.343327144 0.076583722 -4.316073117    -6.064319011    -1.034313982    1.711678831 2.062381759 5.632386548 6.017760438
4.467709087 1.632745678 -2.045736377    -3.601413064    1.695347213 3.295933998 4.070685302 7.743864617 8.348716373
8.256385028 5.635534811 2.707796712 1.572985845 6.066710978 7.095101029 7.941167874 11.37490758 12.15712496
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
-47.4749727 -62.45954133    -69.42311677    -68.04854477    -69.86363461    -56.6566393 -44.02624374    -34.68257496    -5.528397863
-57.44464723    -74.11667952    -83.07777747    -81.88546602    -84.32488173    -72.37428075    -61.04778523    -51.84892678    -20.81696219
-12.6032741 -26.27089119    -36.55478576    -30.40468773    -36.15889518    -33.71339142    -16.63378788    -4.849972012    -1.667644897
-28.28948158    -38.05693676    -43.2879285 -35.34546364    -40.09848824    -34.40754496    -18.41988896    -9.867125675    -7.493617422
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
-35.04117468    -38.74252722    -42.69080876    -43.06064215    -40.85844545    -36.79603495    -37.92408262    -34.51428202    -32.54118632
-29.35688054    -33.7004665 -37.88555224    -39.06340145    -37.19884049    -29.8488303 -32.48244008    -28.52426895    -28.39245064
-1.422800439    -6.972537109    -11.86824507    -13.14543917    -9.893061342    1.11258721  -0.415834635    2.424939039 2.65615071
```

Codes:

```
data=read.table('SMD.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
SMD=data.matrix(data)
p_dry<-0.1542
q_dry<-0.0338
p_wet<-0.1660
q_wet<-0.0333
SMDI<-  matrix(0,nrow=nrow(SMD),ncol=ncol(SMD))
      for (i in 2:nrow(SMD)) {
        for(j in 1:ncol){
        if(is.na(SMD[i,j])){
        SMD[i,j]<-NaN
          SMDI[1,j] <-SMD[1,j]/50
        if(SMD[i,j]<0)
          SMDI[i,j]<- p_dry[j]*SMDI[i-1,j]+SMD[i,j]*q_dry[j] else
          SMDI[i,j]<- p_wet[j]*SMDI[i-1,j]+SMD[i,j]*q_wet[j]
          }                                                                                                
          }
}

write.table(SMDI,(file='SMDI.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loops. In R we works with vectors.

```
SMDIt <- SMD/50 # second equation
# defining vectors of p and q values corresponding to SMDIt
p <- ifelse(SMDIt>0, p_dry, p_wet) 
q <- ifelse(SMDIt>0, q_dry, q_wet)
SMDIt <- p*SMDIt - 1 + q*SMD # first equation
```

Edit: replaced `SMD[, 1]` with `SMD` to calculate values for whole matrix.

Comment: user 151996,                                                                                               It did not worked to me. It gives me only one column, but i need it to run that operations to about 200 columns. i have p_dry and q_dry for greater than 0, and p_wet and q_wet for less than 0. It would be great if u can suggest me doing in data frame. Thanks

Comment: @rosyrana I edited my answer. I thought you wanted to calculate equations for first column only, so I used `SMD[, 1]` (that is first column of `SMD`). I replaced it with `SMD`, so it should work for whole matrix.